# Why do I get None in the output of this code?

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python3. I am trying to write to write a program that in case an input string is even returns the two middle characters and in case it is odd it returns the middle character. I believe the task to be simple but my code returns and unwanted `None` in the output.

```
def get_middle(s):
    if len(s)%2==0:
        #recall that division of two integers outputs a float so I gotta integer it back 
        print(s[int(len(s)/2)-1]+s[int(len(s)/2)])
    else:
        print(s[int(len(s)/2)])


print(get_middle("house"))
print(get_middle("houses"))
```

The output for the code below is

```
u
None
us
None
```

I just don't see where the None is slipping into my code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically when you say `print(get_middle(s))`, python prints what the function returns, which in your case is `None` since there is no `return` statement.

You can do 2 things here:
1. Return the required value from the function and let the code calling the function print it.

```
def get_middle(s):
    if len(s)%2==0:
        #recall that division of two integers outputs a float so I gotta integer it back 
        return s[int(len(s)/2)-1]+s[int(len(s)/2)]
    else:
        return s[int(len(s)/2)]


print(get_middle("house"))
print(get_middle("houses"))
```

2. Avoid print() while calling the function.

I would personally prefer 1 since function is named `ger_middle`, so it should just get you the middle. Doing whatever you want with the middle should be the job of the code that calls it.

Answer (score 1):

`get_middle` doesn't return anything, so when you print its return value, it prints 'None'.

Comment: any ideas on this tree(s) problem:----->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58256987/how-to-update-nodes-of-a-tree-multiple-times

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean to do is `return` the values you calculate inside `get_middle` rather than `print` them. i.e.:

```
def get_middle(s):
    if len(s)%2==0:
        #recall that division of two integers outputs a float so I gotta integer it back 
        return (s[int(len(s)/2)-1]+s[int(len(s)/2)])
    else:
        return (s[int(len(s)/2)])


print(get_middle("house"))
print(get_middle("houses"))
```