# How to update nodes of a tree multiple times?

Tags: algorithm, tree

I encountered an interesting  problem based on tree-data-structure.

> We are given a tree which has *N* nodes, with *1≤N≤10<sup>5</sup>*.
>
> Time starts from second 1 and it continues for *q* seconds.
>
> At each second, the value of each internal node is transferred to all of its child nodes. This happens with all the nodes, except leaf nodes.
>
> Sometimes, at a given time *p* (seconds), we are asked to return the current value of node *x*.

There is this *O(logN)* approach: just find the *p*<sup>th</sup> ancestor of the given node *x*, and output its value.

## A harder version of the same problem

> Sometimes, at a given time *p* (seconds), we are asked to return the current value of node *x*, **or** we are said to update the value of node *x* to *y*.

How to solve this problem for *q* queries (seconds) efficiently, where *1≤q≤10<sup>5</sup>*.

### Example

#### Input

*N*=5, *q*=8

Edges of the tree:-

```
4 3
3 1
5 2
1 2
```

Values of nodes 1 to 5:-

```
1 10 4 9 4
```

Queries:-

- 1<sup>st</sup> second:- `Add(1,6)`. Add the value 6 to node 1.
- 2<sup>nd</sup> second:- What is the current value of node 3? `(?,3)`
- 3<sup>rd</sup> second:- `Add(3,5)`
- 4<sup>th</sup> second:- `(?,3)`
- 5<sup>th</sup> second:- `Add(2,2)`
- 6<sup>th</sup> second:- `Add(5,10)`
- 7<sup>th</sup> second:- `(?,5)`
- 8<sup>th</sup> second:- `(?,4)`

#### Expected Output

- 6
- 0
- 33
- 25

#### Explanation

- 1<sup>st</sup> second: 6,1,1,13,14 (Values of all nodes)
- 2<sup>nd</sup> second: 0,6,6,14,15
- 3<sup>rd</sup> second: 0,0,5,20,21
- 4<sup>th</sup> second: 0,0,0,25,21
- 5<sup>th</sup> second: 0,2,0,25,21
- 6<sup>th</sup> second:  0,0,0,25,33
- 7<sup>th</sup> second: 0,0,0,25,33
- 8<sup>th</sup> second: 0,0,0,25,33

How to answer the queries efficiently?

Comment: It is nowhere mentioned, but is it assumed that node 1 is the root of the tree?

Comment: Also: from your example it becomes clear that a leaf node accumulates the values it receives from its ancestors. If that is indeed correct, then your solution to the "simple" problem is only correct for internal nodes, not for leaf nodes.

Comment: @trincot Yes, "1" is the root of the tree.

Comment: @trincot Yes, I didn't find any solution for leaf nodes :(

Comment: Thank you for your responsiveness :) I will look into this question.

Comment: Are you sure leaves accumulate? This appears nowhere in the problem statement. Same thing about zeroing out the root. Not stated anywhere.

Comment: @n.m. All things you assumed are true..

Comment: Question from live contest 
https://www.codechef.com/OCT19A/problems/BACREP

Comment: Thanks, @ArjunSingh! No answer then before 17 November ;-)

Comment: @trincot it's November 17th :)